# Access stored object on servlet between subsequent RPC calls

Tags: java, gwt, servlets

Is it possible to create on object in the servlet during one RPC request and then access the same object to the next call. Here I create an object "model" in one RPC request (createInstanceParams) then I return to the client, to some other stuff and make another call. Will my object "model" be saved from the previous call or do I have to create it all over again. With each call I'm doing some changes in the "model" object so it is important to know if it is possible. Also, if it possible, an example would be excellent. Thanks. This is my code:

```
public class UpdateModelServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements UpdateModelService {


public Model model;


@Override
public void createInstanceParam(double[] param, ClientModel m) {
    model = new Model(m);
    model.createInstanceParams(param);
}

@Override
public boolean inputFile(String name) {

    return model.inputFile(name);
}

@Override
public ClientModel updateClientModel(ClientModel m) {

    /** 
        model = new Model(m);

        if(...){
            model.inputFile(m.getFileName());
        }
        else if (...){
            model.createInstanceParams(m.getParamList());
    }
    */
    return model.updateClientModel(m);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can store your object in user session:

```
getThreadLocalRequest().getSession().setAttribute("id", obj);
```

and then access it in next rpc call:

```
getThreadLocalRequest().getSession().getAttribute("id");
```